# Per-desktop mutex

Tags: windows, winapi

I've just discovered [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx), and I would like to improve support for it in my application.

I'm using a mutex to prevent multiple instances of the application from running, but I would like to allow to start additional instances if they are launched on a different desktop.

Is it possible to do with a mutex? As far as I know, there are only global and local (per-user) mutex, but no per-desktop mutexes.

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommended use lpDesktop member of the STARTUPINFO struct to compare if application is running on the same desktop or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the mutex

`myCompanyName_myApplicationName_myApplicationVersion_desktopName`

Applications running on different desktops will then be looking at different mutexes.

You can get the desktop name like this, though you might want to add some error checking:

```
wchar_t buffer[256];
DWORD length;

// This desktop handle does not need closing
HANDLE hDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
BOOL succeeded = GetUserObjectInformation(hDesktop, UOI_NAME, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &length);
// if succeeded then desktop name is in buffer
```